# Problem with ASPx controls from DevExpress

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

I am using aspx controls from dev express.

The issue I am having is that they seem to have some sort of footer on them that restricts the size, maybe the picture will explain better.

[image: screenshot].

At the top is a date edit and the bottom is a grid. Both seem to have this gutter.

I am using the 960 grid, a master page and css. I am not using any panels or anything like that as I am trying to keep the markup as clean as possible.

Has anyone seen this before? I've tried to remove the footer but I don't think that is what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have some sort of style that is adding space to the header, footer, and filter fields.  I would remove any reference to a .css from the page and see if the problem goes away.  If it does, look for the style that may be causing the problem.  IF it doesn't then it is likely a style setting on the grid itself.

Comment: Your a legend! It was the text.css that comes with 960.gs. You will have to forgive me, I have been trust into this project with no previous experience of web dev so it's trial by fire :) Green tick in 8 mins.